# Where does DefaultCredentials pull out "UserName" as a username for a web request?

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, defaultnetworkcredentials, credentialscache

There's a `WinForms` desktop application which tries to connect to `SSRS` service. The Reporting Server is configured to accept both Active Directory credential logins and also a credential for specific user for reporting purposes. In the following code section we use a `WinForms` `ReportViewer`:

```
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(_dboardServices.ReportingServicesUrl);
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

This works fine on my fellow developer's machine, and for most of our clients. But some clients experience 401: `System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized`, coming from the SoapHttpClient system.
Interestingly I can reproduce this issue on my machine. Looking into the traffic with `Fiddler`, an `NTLM` authentication starts, and then "UserName" (literally!) sent as a username instead of my real username. Obviously that fails.

If I construct a credential with the right username, password and domain (`reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = new NetworkCredential(goodUserName, goodPassword, domain);`) my request succeeds. Just as if I navigate to the `SSRS` `asmx` link and type in my credentials. But `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` (which should default to my AD credentials) pulls out this "UserName" from somewhere. Where does the system gets that from? I searched our source code and the web with no luck so far.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey In the meantime I've found it out and you are right. Please write an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely an issue with stored credentials. See what credentials you have stored by running `control keymgr.dll` at the command line. See this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/archive/2009/09/03/using-httpwebrequest-with-credential-manager.aspx).

Comment: So the mysterious credential was pulled out from the credential cache (what a surprise!), I haven't checked it since I didn't think I have specific stuff there. `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` only defaults to my AD credentials, if there's nothing in the credential cache for the same host. I used `rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr` to display the Credential Manager, someone can navigate to it from Control Panel too.